# Replace Placeholder in Text File with Shell Script maybe with sed or awk

Tags: shell, awk, sed, placeholder

I have an input file and every line has always 3 values separated with a ","

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
....
```

Every line should be pasted in a template File and for every line a own File written with a continuous number like 01.txt 02.txt

template.txt

```
<wpt col="value1" cal="value2"><name>value3</name></wpt>
```

How can I achieve this?
On this machine, I can only use shell scripts. No python or other languages are available and also can not installed

Comment: [edit] your question to add your attempted code so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

##### Using `printf`

```
c=0
while IFS=, read -r c1 c2 c3; do
    ((c++))
    printf -v count '%.2d' $c
    printf '<wpt col="value%d" cal="value%d"><name>value%d</name></wpt>\n' \
        $c1 $c2 $c3 > "$count.txt"
done < file
```

##### Using a shell template file with variables and `envsubst`:

`man envsubst`

> envsubst - substitutes environment variables in shell format strings

```
cat template.tpl 
<wpt col="value$c1" cal="value$c2"> <name>value$c3</name></wpt>
```

```
c=0
while IFS=, read -r c1 c2 c3; do
    ((c++))
    printf -v count '%.2d' $c
    export c1=$c1 c2=$c2 c3=$c3
    envsubst < template.tpl > "$count.txt"
done < file
```

Then

```
ls -1 *.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

An approach with `awk`, using `sprintf` to format the numbers in output file names.

Keep in mind that this overwrites existing files with the same names.

```
% awk -F ',' '{
    nr=sprintf("%02d", NR)
    print "<wpt col=\""$1"\" cal=\""$2"\"><name>"$3"</name></wpt>" > (nr".txt"); close(nr".txt")
  }' file
```

or, including reading in the *template.txt* file

```
% awk -F ',' 'NR==FNR{tem=$0; next} 
    {nr=sprintf("%02d", FNR)
     sub(/col=.* /, "col=\""$1"\" ", tem)
     sub(/cal=.*\"><name/, "cal=\""$2"\"><name", tem)
     sub(/<name>.*<\/name>/, "<name>"$3"</name>", tem)
     print tem > (nr".txt"); close(nr".txt")}' template.txt file
```

Result

```
% cat 01.txt
<wpt col="1" cal="2"><name>3</name></wpt>
% cat 02.txt
<wpt col="4" cal="5"><name>6</name></wpt>
```

Comment: you need to close files: `'{print ...> (nr".txt");close(nr".txt")}'` and to englobe it with parenthesis.

Comment: @GillesQuénot Ah, thanks, always forget these things! Gonna edit!

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed and split):

```
sed -E 's/(.*),(.*),(.*)/<wpt col="\1" cal="\2"><name>\3<\/name><\/wpt>/' file |
split -l1 --add=.txt --numeric=01 - ''
```

Manipulate each line of the file into the required format, then split each line into a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I'd wait to see your attempt to solve the problem first so I could help with your code but since you already have answers...

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="," }
NR==FNR {
    tmplt = $0 ORS
    gsub(/value[0-9]+/,"%s",tmplt)
    next
}
{
    out = sprintf("%02d.txt", FNR)
    printf tmplt, $1, $2, $3 > out
    close(out)
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk template.txt file
```

```
$ head 0*.txt
==> 01.txt <==
<wpt col="1" cal="2"><name>3</name></wpt>

==> 02.txt <==
<wpt col="4" cal="5"><name>6</name></wpt>
```

The above will work using any awk and just assumes your template line doesn't contain any `printf` formatting characters such as `%s` and `value[0-9]+` only matches in the desired contexts.

Answer (score 0):

don't waste time do it one by one. just use `awk` to mass generate `printf` statements then use a lightweight shell to execute them all at once (with the added bonus of not having to close files nonstop in `awk`) :

```
gfind . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grm -v 
ls -nAlFrt
```

---

```
removed './01.txt'
removed './02.txt'
removed './03.txt'
total 0
```

---

```
echo $'1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9' | 

mawk '$!NF=sprintf("printf \47%%s\47 \47<wpt col=\"%s\" cal=\"%s\"><name" \
           ">%s</name></wpt>\47 > \47%.2d.txt\47 ;",$1,$2,$3,NR)' FS=',' | 

gtee >( gpaste | gcat -n >&2; cat ) | dash
```

---

```
     1  printf '%s' '<wpt col="1" cal="2"><name>3</name></wpt>' > '01.txt' ;
     2  printf '%s' '<wpt col="4" cal="5"><name>6</name></wpt>' > '02.txt' ;
     3  printf '%s' '<wpt col="7" cal="8"><name>9</name></wpt>' > '03.txt' ;
```

---

```
ls -nAlFrt
```

---

```
total 12
-rw-r--r--  1 501  20  41 May  8 08:29 01.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 501  20  41 May  8 08:29 02.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 501  20  41 May  8 08:29 03.txt
```

---

```
for __ in *.txt; do 

   gcat  -n "$__"
   echo "\n\t$__\n"

done
```

---

```
     1  <wpt col="1" cal="2"><name>3</name></wpt>
    01.txt

     1  <wpt col="4" cal="5"><name>6</name></wpt>
    02.txt

     1  <wpt col="7" cal="8"><name>9</name></wpt>
    03.txt
```